# Backbone change class with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

I am trying to change the class of a button when another button is clicked. I am able to change css on the page but have been unable to change `btn-primary` to `btn-default`.

Button:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" id="circle-1">1</button>
```

View:

```
events: {
        "click #activate-step-2"    : "newParent"
    },

    newParent: function(event) {

                $('#step-1').css({'display':'none'});
                 $('#step-2').css({'display':'initial'});


    }
```

I have tryed:

```
$(event.target).find('button').toggleClass('btn-primary btn-default')
```

But it didnt work,

so i'm not sure what else to try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#circle-1").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
```